# SQL query with a syntax error with DATE_ADD() function (edited)

Tags: mysql

I'm writing some SQL queries, and an error occurred:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 10: ... AND A2.block_time < DATE_ADD(A1.block_time, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

My query where the error occurred is:

```
SELECT address_id
FROM address_history A1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM address_history A2
    WHERE A1.address_id = A2.address_id
    AND A1.inflow = A2.outflow
    AND A2.block_time > A1.block_time
    AND A2.block_time < DATE_ADD(A1.block_time, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND A1.address_id IN ( ... )          # some candidates
)
```

and data in the block_time column are of the form:

```
2020-01-03 14:10:00
```

so I don't think I need to cast data with CAST() or DATE(). What's wrong with this SQL query?

**Part of my Python code**

```
        mySQL_user = '''
                  SELECT address_id
                  FROM address_history A1
                  WHERE EXISTS (
                      SELECT *
                      FROM address_history A2
                      WHERE A1.address_id = A2.address_id
                      AND A1.inflow = A2.outflow
                      AND A2.block_time > A1.block_time
                      AND A2.block_time < DATE_ADD(A1.block_time, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                      AND A1.address_id IN (
                  '''
```

Above code is the skeleton of my query, and I appended some candidates using:

```
mySQL_user += f"'{address}'"
```

where address is a string variable. I also separated candidates using ", "(comma), and I added two ")" at the end using:

```
mySQL_user += "))"
```

Comment: what is the column type of A1.block_time?

Comment: I still don't see any problem with your query.

Comment: @danblack: A1.block_time column's data are of the form: 2019-12-31 23:59:59

Comment: @AABBCC is `A1.block_time` a date or a varchar type?

Comment: obtainable via `show create table address_history`;

Comment: if i count the lines, LINE 10 is `  AND A1.address_id IN ( ... )          # some candidates` you are sure that this is the statement that produce the error?

Comment: @Jens: I wrote the query on Python, so there is ''' on the first line. Sorry for confusion. By the way, how can I figure out the type of A1.block_time?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid MySQL query (other than the `...` in the `IN` expression which I assume you have omitted for brevity).

Comment: @AABBCC use the command which is sugeested by danblack

Comment: If you wrote it in python. show us the code please

Comment: @Jens: I'll edit it.

Comment: @Jens: I edited.

Comment: @danblack: It says that block_time is a type of 'timestamp without time zone'

Comment: ok, the type was a little wrong track [as it works regardless of type](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e211254ebe31b76276abc3ae0d1d2cf). Looking closer at the error,  it isn't the `date_add`. MySQL errors point to the exact start of where the syntax error occurred. Can you edit the question and show exactly the start of the LINE 10: without removing at the beginning of the error message.